# Какой подход лучше для организации API и серверной части?

Tags: php, ооп, api, архитектура

Всем привет. Мне хотелось бы реализовать headless приложение, которые одинаково работало бы как при обычных (веб) запросах пользователя на сайте, так и API. Например, если пользователь обратится по адресу `/structure/workers`, то ему отобразится список всех исполнителей, а если через API, то вернется ответ в формате JSON.

На текущий момент я представляю такую схему, что есть какой-то класс-сервис, который возвращает массив данных после выполнения бизнес логики. В зависимости от обращения контроллер или что-то другое, которые оперирует запросами и ответами, анализирует метод обращения и нужным образом возвращает данные.

Вопрос только к организации API и Server части так, чтобы методы API были доступны не по аналогичному пути. То есть, `/structure/workers` - серверная часть, `/api//structure/workers` - API часть. Все они будут вызывать, условно, `class StructreService`, который вернет уже данные. Но тут не очень понимаю, как реализовать единую прослойку, чтобы не писать 2 контроллера для API и Server части.

Есть какие-то идеи или архитектуры для моей задачи с максимальным использованием ООП?

Comment: А зачем городить огород без необходимости? Делаете проверку на Content-Type при входящем запросе, и в зависимости от него выдаёте данные либо в JSON, либо в HTML. По сути тут можно обойтись наследованиями сериализаторов ваших структур ответа, чтобы в зависимости от типа запрашиваемых данных делать их сериализацию. Пути API  иметь одни и те же.

Comment: Ну тут вопрос больше про автоматизацию такого. То есть эти вещи могу существовать друг от друга раздельно, а вот прокладка как раз в автоматизированном варианте будет вызывать тот или иной "контроллер". Типа контроллер, который вызовет типовой контроллер... Не знаю, как лучше объяснить это

Comment: @mepihindeveloper мне кажется достаточно просто иметь маршрутизатор, который в зависимости от url направлять в нужный контроллер. А уже сами контроллеры что API, что WEB, что Desktop и пр - должны просто наследоваться от `BaseApplicationController`, в котором будет общая логика и методы